# Why would I use remote debugging other than hardware issues?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Can you provide some examples of when and why you have used remote debugging in your projects? The only reason I can think of is to debug for hardware issues. Are there any other benefits? I am particularly interested in Visual Studio remote debugging.

Comment: Debugging GUI issues that involve focus or window activation.  Debugging a mouse or keyboard hook.

Comment: Generally asking for "list of things" is off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I've used remote debugging in cases where a user is getting an exception or some other unexpected behavior that I can't reproduce on my dev machine.  It's very handy to be able to attach to a remote process and step through code that's running on another machine.

Computers where your software runs can differ in many ways -- yes, hardware -- but also in software configurations: differing setting values or settings that are missing entirely, missing files/directories or files with differing access levels; the list goes on and on.

Comment: I can vouch for having a problem along the lines of "missing files/directories", we had an issue where a configuration file was not being cleaned from the server's instance of a program when we re-published which caused unexpected behavior that could only be detected with remote debugging.